# Is function block diagram functional programming?

Tags: functional-programming, plc

Is *function block diagram* that is used for programming plc systems a form of functional programming?

Comment: Take a PID function block fed with a low pass filter. Both blocks have state. You don’t want the same output from the filter for the same input; it needs to be based off past inputs.  If the temperature of your PID is a few degrees off, you want the control value to change to get it back to set point. This means inconsistent output for same input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to approach this, is looking at the Wikipedia page for functional programming.

> 2 Concepts
>
> ```
> 2.1 First-class and higher-order functions
> 2.2 Pure functions
> 2.3 Recursion
> 2.4 Strict versus non-strict evaluation
> 2.5 Type systems
> ```

To sum up, for FBD programming, we have:

- 2.1 - Nope
- 2.2 - Nope (access to global memory in DB, Q and M areas)
- 2.3 - Disallowed
- 2.4 - Sort of not applicable, but lazy evaluation is out of the question
- 2.5 - No. The type system is not user definable, at least not in the FP sense

So, that's a big no I'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. What puts functional programming apart is that it treats computation as the evaluation of mathematical functions [(see Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). The function blocks in PLC programming is simply a convenient way to group and reuse code in a manner that enables even "non-programmers" to use it.